# Inserting rows after each group and sum a particular contents of a column based on the group

Tags: vba, excel, openpyxl

I have data in consective rows, however they are sorted in name column, i.e. (which is 'A' as for now but could change)

```
>    A      B   C
>     Name1 123 rdt
>     Name1 256 efh
>     Name1 456 ikj
>     Name2 123 rfa
>     Name3 654 xxd
>     Name3 846 olp
>     Name6 841 yuf
```

I want to insert a row (or two, any number of rows) after each group of names i.e. and sum colum 'B'

```
  A     B   C
    Name1   123 rdt
    Name1   256 efh
    Name1   456 ikj
        =sum(above number of Name1s)
    Name2   123 rfa
        =sum(above number of Name2s)
    Name3   654 xxd
    Name3   846 olp
        =sum(above number of Name3s)
    Name6   841 yuf
```

I have similar problem to the question here 
AWK: Insert a row after each group of data
[AWK: Insert a row after each group of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874258/awk-insert-a-row-after-each-group-of-data)  but with Excel.

Also, is it possible to do that in Python with openpyxl, if so how? Please!

Thank you

Comment: please take the time to format it correctly for better readability

Comment: It was beautifully formatted before uploading, but when i posted it got messed up. How can I upload a picture?

Comment: Kindly refer to my profile picture so that it becomes easier to see what I am asking. Please

Comment: i think new users cannot link inline images. in future, use code format for tables (4 spaces before the line)

Comment: Done, I figured, but thanks @nj2237

Comment: Just use either the `Data --> Subtotal` wizard; or a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sum As Double

    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        i = 1
        Do
            If .Cells(i + 1, 1) = .Cells(i, 1) Then
                sum = sum + .Cells(i, 2)
                i = i + 1
            Else
                sum = sum + .Cells(i, 2)
                i = i + 1
                .Rows(i).Insert xlDown
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = sum
                i = i + 1
                sum = 0
            End If
        Loop While i <= .Rows.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and give feed back, (accept your answer and rate it), after I start windows. (on Linux right now dual boot).

But this means there is no Python code for this?